# IIS6 fails to start on Windows Server 2003 SP2

Tags: iis-6, windows-update, wsus

I installed IIS after installing SP2 on Windows 2003 R2. IIS never starts. I tried re-installing IIS, but that failed.

One of those 'dash' sites suggested re-installing SP2. When I attempted this, I got an access denied error -- I was logged in at an Admin level.

The goal is to put WSUS 3sp1 on this server.

The App and System logs have no information; however, the World Wide Web Publishing Service never installs.

Comment: What did you do to start it? Look in event logs and edit your post to include the event log errors.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was giving Administrators Full Control of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SvcHost key.

I had to uninstall IIS, and then re-install IIS, followed by repairing Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0. You may have to reboot after re-installing IIS. At this point, the Web Publishing Service finally installed, which allowed me to install WSUS 3 sp1.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Application event log and you should find error messages that tell you why IIS6 wouldn't start. If they seem too cryptic post them here and we can have a look.

JR

Comment: No App or System log info.